# SyntaxHighlighter with php to load page?

Tags: java, highlighting, syntaxhighlighter

I am attempting to use Alex Gorbatchevs Syntax Highlighter in conjunction with a variety of java examples.  Instead of copying and pasting each example into its own html page, I would love to use php to get the filename and path, and then load the text content in between the "pre" tags... something like

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
include ("$filename");
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Obviously, since it is in between the "pre" tags, this renders like

```
include("$filename");
```

with pretty highlighting... =P

Is there anything that will work for me?  Or am I stuck with copying and pasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure? I have reproduced the scenario and works fine for me:

code.php

```
<? echo "this is my code"; ?>
```

syntax.php

```
<?
$filename = "code.php";

echo "<pre>";
include("$filename");
echo "</pre>";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
     SyntaxHighlighter.all()
</script>
```

output:

```
1  this is my code
```

Comment: You are correct sir.  The problem was the fact that I am a moron and was expecting the php scripts to work correctly when I viewed them in a browser like an html page.  I uploaded the pages to a webhost, and this works perfectly.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the include() method to do this - rather have a read / play with php's "fopen" command. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: The issue is not that I can't import the text, it's the fact that any command contained between the <pre> tags is not executed...

Comment: I thought that was the point of a syntax highlighter, so that you can see code, and not execute it?